# Best database for multiple-column indexes?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search-engine, document-database

I have a sparse database. Some fields are of Boolean type (these fields should be indexed), some other fields are of Nominal type (again, these fields should also be indexed) whereas some other fields are of Text type (but those ones should not be indexed). I would like to save my data in a database so that I can search based on any combination of the indexed fields and get back the results. Should I consider using Elasticsearch, MongoDB or another databases?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to above mentioned description I suggest MongoDB is best suitable for your requirement as MongoDB has powerful index management and it supports multiple types of indexes.

> Indexes allow MongoDB to process and fulfill queries quickly by
>   creating small and efficient representations of the documents in a
>   collection.

For more detailed description regarding index types in mongodb please refer the documentation  mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/